# Read JSON file in python: ValueError

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I have a .txt file with 70+k json object obtained by pulling data from twitter and dumping into file using:

```
with open("followers.txt", 'a') as f:
     for follower in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=account_name).pages()):
         for user_obj in follower:
             json.dump(user_obj._json, f)  
             f.write("\n")
```

When I try to read this in python using the code below:

```
import json
with open('followers.txt') as json_data:
     follower_data = json.load(json_data)
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 2801 column 1 (char 1489 - 8679498)
```

It worked when I read a test file with one json object copied from the original file using the same code above. Once I add a second json object to this file then using the same code above gives the error:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 2 column 2376 (char 1489 - 3864)
```

How do I read the file with more than one json object?

Comment: You're not writing it correctly, so you cannot read it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is best to treat the problem from the root: write a single json and read it, as suggested by [COLDSPEED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182349/1714410).
However, if you already wrote multiple json objects into a single file, you can try the following code to use the already created file:

```
import json
follower_data = []  # a list of all objects
with open('followers.txt') as json_data:
  for line in json_data:
    follower_data.append( json.loads(line) )
```

Assuming you did not indent your json objects when you wrote them to `'flowers.txt'`, then each line in the file is a json object that can be parsed independantly.

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly to load data already written in multiple json objects.

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes when you write your JSON. You must write a single JSON object, so you may also load a single JSON object. Currently, you are writing multiple separate objects, causing the error.

Modify your write code a bit:

```
json_data = []
with open("followers.txt", 'a') as f:
     for follower in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=account_name).pages()):
         for user_obj in follower:
             json_data.append(user_obj._json)             

     # outside the loops
     json.dump(json_data, f)
```

Now, when reading, your existing code should work. You'll get a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. I have updated my write code.

Comment: @T-Jay if you used my answer then you should accept mine man ;p Just kidding.